# Listing the content of a Drive ( without exceeding quotas)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I have an folder in a Google Drive which contains Archives of the last 40 years. I want to get the name of each of the file in this folder with their ids in a Google Sheet.

I wrote a Google Script to read all the content of the folder and to append the informations of each file on a specific Google Sheet. The Google Sheet is totally cleare and reconstructed each time I run the script.

```
while(contenuDossierRapports.hasNext()) {
  rapport = contenuDossierRapports.next();

  nom_rapport = rapport.getName().split(".")[0];
  id = rapport.getId();
  telechargement = "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=" + id;
  if (nom_rapport != "Rapports") {
   feuille.appendRow( [ nom_rapport, telechargement, id] );
  }       
}
```

A Google Script can only run for a total of 6 minutes top and since I have too many files, the script only has time to write the informations of around 2000 files. Do you have an idea on how to achieve what I want without having to upgrade my account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to get just the file id's and then do them in batches of 1000.

```
function getFileNames() {
  var fA=[];
  var folder=DriveApp.getFolderById('FolderId')
  var files=folder.getFiles();
  while(files.hasNext()) {
    fA.push(files.next().getId());
  }
  Logger.log(fA.join('~~~'));
}
```

However you do it.  It boils down to figuring out how to do it in smaller batches.

Comment: See also: [Best Practices for Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices)

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't find this website and its very usfeul! The thing I don't understand in doing things in batches is won't it exceed the quota? The way I see it is you'd have to to recursive calls to a function but the timer wouldn't reset so it would still timeout?

Comment: The idea is to use some sort of a time based  trigger to initiate each call with enough time between calls to insure that the batch completes.  You will have to store the next item location either in cache or PropertiesService.